# Convert PDF text as image to MOBI

Tags: gratis, pdf, ocr, file-conversion, mobi

I have a few public domain PDFs which someone has simply scanned and the converted the .JPEG to .PDF.

Which gratis app can convert them to .MOBI, retaining as much formatting as possible (btw, it would be a bonus to lose the images in conversion; not must have, but don't worry about retaining them)

---

[Update] I have tried using FoxIt reader and File/Save as ... text

That worked reasonably well, but the text was poorly formatted. Some paragraphs, or even longer lines, were split onto multiple lines.

Maybe I could use that method with some kind of text formatter which is aware of sentences, paragraphs?  Any suggestions?

Comment: You might read this just in case it sounds relevant to you... [Post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21928)

Comment: The title seems relevant, but the post is not He wants to change the background of a PNG from transparent to solid white - using LaTex

Comment: Something that works well going from PDF to Word is a Nuance production that keeps most of the formatting [Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/imaging-solutions/document-conversion/power-pdf-converter/standard/index.htm). I think they have a trial version you could get to confirm though in case that will work and I suppose there are batch options as well so you may be able to do some command line and process groups of files in large batches for the conversions for your needs. Something else to look into I assume just in case but works well for one company I support for their needs